# unable to assign updated value to ssis variable using script task

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I created some variables and using the C# script task I am trying to modifying the values of the variables.
initial values

Expression Builder image for pine variable

[image]
    FolderInputPath="D:\";
    Pine="C:\abc\qwr";

please find the variable status

[image]

the above values were set at the variables in ssis package

```
string filename = "";
string newname="";
filename = Dts.Variables["User::FolderInputPath"].Value.ToString();

if (filename.Substring(filename.Length - 1, 1) != "\\")
{
    filename = filename + "\\";
}

newname = filename + "Pine.txt";
Dts.Variables["User::Pine"].Value = newname;
MessageBox.Show(newname + "     before value is " + Dts.Variables["User::Pine"].Value.ToString());
```

As per the above logic we `User::Pine` should have the value "D:\Pine.txt" but when i run the code the value for the variable `User::Pine`doesn't change

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure to mark the variables as Read/Write and not just as ReadOnly on the script component.

Comment: All variables were readwrite

Comment: Check if your variable is set to "Evaluate as expression" on the Properties tab (F4). Undo if so.

Comment: EzLo I have updated my question, please check and confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the variable pane, click on your variable and press F4 to open the Properties window.

Make sure that "EvaluateAsExpression" and "ReadOnly" are both set to **False**. Also make sure that the "Expression" field is **empty** (like the following image). If it's not, select it's text and delete it.

[image: ![enter image description here]